# What is this Hogwarts Tower?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, hogwarts

I recently went to Harry Potter world, towards the end is a huge model of Hogwarts they used to film the outside shots.

I noticed this tower

[image]

It stands a long way (over the other side of the bridge) from the main castle and I can't see a Whomping Willow nearby so I really don't think it's the Shrieking Shack!

Here's a second (slightly blurry) image from another angle

[image]

What is this isolated tower?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in working with "miniatures" the camera angle is very important. It might be positioned so far away to give it scale.

Comment: if i had to guess its the astronomy tower

Comment: I guess there were any subject matter experts on hand at the exhibit to ask?

Comment: @Xantec alas my wife didn't know either! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically speaking, this is the [**West Tower**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/West_Tower). The small jutting tower on the main tower's side is the [Owlery](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Owlery), leading to the tower being informally known as the '*Owlery Tower*'.

It's mentioned repeatedly in the books and [games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNjvM09Y0KM).

> *He then climbed out of the portrait hole, up through the silent castle
>   (held up only briefly by Peeves, who tried to overturn a large vase on
>   him halfway along the fourth-floor corridor), finally arriving at the
>   Owlery, which was situated at the top of West Tower.* - <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

---

The tower is depicted in great detail in the [games](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/West_Tower?file=West_Tower.jpg), but only fleetingly in the films, such as this snap from Deathly Hallows, Part II

[image]

And this scene where Harry gets shot down in flames by Cho.

Comment: This is also the owlery in the Lego HP game. You can walk down some long path and you come to this tower separated from the rest of the castle and inside are tons of owls. +1

Answer (score 7):

I believe it is the Hogwarts Owlery. A brief Google Images search returned other images of this model, described as such.

[image]

Comment: On the steps up to the tower visible in this picture the best is where Harry asked Cho to go to the Yule Ball and that was definitely the Owlery.