# Which tower did Harry go to in Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Harry Potter and Cho Chang talk for the first time in a tower.

> Cho: Watch yourself on the steps. It's a bit icy on the top
>
> Harry: Okay. Thanks

Harry Potter asks her to go to the Yule Ball with him, but she says someone has already asked her and she said she would go with him and apologises.

When they meet they almost crash into each other. It is clear that their meeting was not planned. It is not explained in the movie why and where Cho Chang and Harry Potter went.

What is that tower where Harry Potter and Cho Chang bumped into each other? Why were they there? Is it explained in the books?

Comment: Isn't it the owlery?

Comment: @Edlothiad O haven't read books 1 to 4. I only watched movies. I don't know which tower it is. That is why I'm asking the question. I think it is owlery. but why did Cho and Harry go there?

Comment: @NogShine They had both gone to owlery to send parcel. Harry was writing to Sirius and Cho was sending a last minute Birthday present to her Mom if I remember right

Comment: Possible dupe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127237/what-is-this-hogwarts-tower/127253#127253

Comment: @Valorum I think the question here is really what was the purpose of their visit, and can be easily changed without vandalising the answers, or changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah. As Edlothiod said, the main question was why did they go there.

Comment: I think the question should specify that it was asked in relation to the movie, because in the book it is pretty clear that it was the owlery

Comment: @user13267 There is a line already " It is not explained in the movie why and where Cho Chang and Harry Potter went". What should I add more?

Comment: I meant including the movie tag. I had added it already but looks like someone deleted it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### It's the Owlery.

This is clear from the clip below, as you can see Owls flying around and their cages behind. This seems to match the scene that occurs one book later, with Cho and Harry bumping into each other at the Owlery

> The Owlery door opened behind him. He leapt in shock, and turning quickly, saw Cho Chang holding a letter and a parcel in her hands...
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix: Chapter 14, Percy and Padfoot</sub>

The conversation goes on to be a similarly awkward conversation as the one from the film, however the intentions of both characters are clear. Cho went to send her mother a birthday gift:

> ... I only remembered five minutes ago, it's my mum's birthday
> She held up the parcel
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

whereas Harry was sending a letter for Sirius, telling him about Umbridge and asking about Hargid:

> Dear Snuffles,
> Hope you're okay, the first week back here's been terrible, I'm really glad it's the weekend.
> We've got a new Defense (sic) Against the Dark Arts teacher, Professor Umbridge. She's nearly as nice as your mum. I'm writing because that thing I wrote to you about last summer happened again last night when I was doing a detention with Umbridge.
> We're all missing our biggest friend, we hope he'll be back soon.
> Please write back quickly.
> Best,
> Harry.

> "Right I know it says 'Snuffles' on the outside," he told her [Hedwig], giving her the letter to clasp in her beak and, without knowing exactly why, whispering, "but it's for Sirius ok?"
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

although for the film the scene has been moved from OotP to GoF.

Comment: 'We've got a new Defense (sic) Against the Dark Arts teacher, Professor Umbridge.' Just saying that the (sic) isn't needed.. or was it Harry actually writing that because it wasn't really defence? If not that it would be dependent on the publisher. Maybe I remember wrong though?

Comment: @Pryftan it was a joke. Actually it may not have been a joke, I can't recall where I got the quote from

Comment: Ha. Right. That totally went over me. I'm ashamed even. Or am I? I mean I thought you had added it because technically it should be 'defence' but the idea it was for humour completely evaded me. Thanks for clarifying; whether it was meant for humour or not I prefer it that way!